# Polymer website "breaks" Pagespeed Insights

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, pagespeed

Newly built Polymer site has just been released but causes Google's PageSpeed Insights to break [here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fupperdog.co.uk). The site's url is https://upperdog.co.uk. Any information would be appreciated

Thanks